# How can I make a select/deselect all check box in VBA, that only works on certain checkboxes?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a dashboard with four interactive graphs. They function with check boxes with format control, so that checking e.g. the "USA" box changes a cell from TRUE to FALSE. The TRUE/FALSE statement then informs whether the USA data should be showed in the graph.

I have made a select/deselect all checkbox, however, when you press it, it selects/deselects all boxes in all four graphs.

I am looking for an edition to my macro, where I can specify which boxes each of the four select/deselect all boxes should affect.

This is the code I am using for my select/deselect checkbox:

```
Sub AllCheckboxes()

Dim cb As CheckBox

For Each cb In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes

    If cb.Name <> ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Check Box 1").Name Then
        cb.Value = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Check Box 1").Value
    End If
        
Next
        
End Sub
```

I have three of those named AllCheckboxes 2, 3, 4, and with different names (Check Box 1, 2, 3 and 4).

Hope you understand my issue!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's a list of ways you could go... You could assess the ComboBox you to `Select` "USA" wherein each `Case` would change the boolean checkboxes, as one option.  Knowing more about your form may be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am not really sure how to explain it further - the country boxes have simply been linked to a cell, so that when a country box is selected, another cell shows TRUE (and FALSE if not selected).

Looking for a macro or similar that can select/deselect 9 specific boxes, instead of the current one which selects/deselects 4x9 boxes. 

Hope that makes it more clear!

Comment: Is the country box a radio/option button?  You can loop through all checkboxes, set value to false for each, then use the set value to true for only the specific country imparted checkboxes... this is extremely similar to what Tim wrote below, part of where i had `select` and `case` in my previous comment.  How you determine the country will provide the final necessary info.

Comment: Thanks Cyril. I am very new to VBA, so had a hard time understanding your input, but I do appreciate it nonetheless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a single Sub for this - check the name of the calling checkbox and use that to identify the linked checkboxes to be set.

```vb
Sub AllCheckboxes()
    
    Dim arr, cb As Object, cbName
    
    'which checkbox was clicked, and which are its "linked" boxes?
    Select Case Application.Caller
        Case "Check Box 1": arr = Array("Check Box 2", "Check Box 3", _
                                        "Check Box 4", "Check Box 5")
        
        Case "Check Box 6": arr = Array("Check Box 7", "Check Box 8", _
                                        "Check Box 9", "Check Box 10")
    End Select
    
    If Not IsEmpty(arr) Then 'got a match?
        Set cb = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(Application.Caller) 'the calling checkbox
        For Each cbName In arr
            ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(cbName).Value = cb.Value
        Next cbName
    End If
    
End Sub
```

As an alternative to using arrays, you could use a naming convention such that (eg) clicking "CheckBox_A" sets "CheckBox_A_1", "CheckBox_A_2", etc